# How can i iterate through all the data (data1, data2, date3) in nested object to Validate the Data?

Tags: javascript

how can i iterate through all the data object (data1, data2 ...) and validate the data like
if data1.name == input print matched else didn't matched?

```
const input = "aman"

const api = {
    data1 : {
        name : "aman",
        age : 22
    },
    data2 : {
        name : "anuj",
        age : 20
    },
    data3 : {
        name : "rahul",
        age : 22
    },
}
```

Comment: If you have `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, consider using an array. Please share your code so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it like this

```
Object.keys(api).forEach(function(key) {
    if(api[key].name==input){
        console.log("Matched")
    }
    })
```

Comment: but it shows both result - matched and didn't match

Comment: usually you would want both cases but anyway ive updated the code and removed else block. it will only show matched now.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `for in`. for more document you can check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

[image]

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) -- it also applies to answers. This also doesn't do what OP asked.